# Sql Server How To Parse a String With Good Performance

Tags: sql-server, string, parsing, wildcard, in-clause

I'm trying to isolate a specific return value in a string that has combined several values in one field in a table in SQL Server. The data is separated by a consistent delimiter, but the combined values are not always in the same order.

Example - Here are three rows of data as a sample:

- Row 1 #Name:John Doe#City:New York#State:NY
- Row 2 #State:CA#Name:Jane Smith#City:Los Angeles
- Row 3 #City:San Diego#State:CA#Name:John Smith
- Row 4 #City:Houston#State:TX#Name:Jane Doe

In the above, I'd want to return the 'City' which in this example would simply return:

- New York
- Los Angeles
- San Diego
- Houston

At other times I'd want to return the Name or the State.

So far I've come up the following code, but it seems like it would not perform well.

```
SELECT 
    Left(SUBSTRING([MyField], CHARINDEX('#Name:', [MyField]) + Len('#Name:'), 10000), CHARINDEX('#', SUBSTRING([MyField], CHARINDEX('#Name:', [MyField]) + Len('#Name:'), 1000)) - 1) As MyColumn 
FROM 
    MyTable
```

Does anyone have any better ideas that will perform well or be simpler?

---

For those interested here's a side note:

Ultimately I want to use this in a where clause with an "In" clause to find any given cities, names, or states.  Since the "In" clause does not support wild cards (correct me if I'm wrong) I thought I'd attack it from the left side of the criteria.

For example, since this doesn't work (assume the same data sample as above):

```
Select * From MyTable Where MyField In ('%#City:Los Angeles', '%#City: San Diego')
```

I'm trying to do this instead (assume the 'ParseMyField' is a function that has the text I used above or something like it that performs better):

```
Select * From MyTable Where ParseMyField(MyField) In ('Los Angeles', 'San Diego')
```

Comment: Any reason it needs to be `IN` rather than a bunch of LIKE/OR `(LIKE '%#City:Los Angeles%' OR LIKE '%#City: San Diego%')`. You might want to consider using full text search although it won't nicely split the types of data out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx. Any db person will tell you this design is not scalable and if you have the option you should redesign it to be normalised. Both the `LIKE` and the `CHARINDEX` options stop usage of indexes which is bad for database performance.

Comment: Doesn't have to be an IN clause but went that route because thought it would be easier. The lookup values can be different/variable so I'm going to dynamically build the values being passed to the IN clause and thought it be easier to that then dynamically build a bunch of LIKE/OR. I'm open to change if the advise is it would be better

Comment: you might want to re-think your table design. This is definately not a good one.

Comment: A LIKE/OR construct means you can use wildcards and you don't need to use a large nested string expression (which also need to include allowances for when the tag doesn't exist - if CHARINDEX returns 0 and you subtract 1 from that). Both an IN expression and a LIKE/OR expression would need to be dynamically built. If you expect to get any volume of data in this table (like a million rows) then you need to know that you are going to struggle with performance as indexes can't be used in either case. As already suggested, you need to redesign this if you have the opportunity.

Comment: I didn't design the table or the data string by the way. Its from a thrid party source and that's how it comes in. Just now figuring how to work with it

Comment: Just throwing it out there, you might be better off doing this in a CLR proc.

Comment: The fact that the data comes in from external source in this format doesn't mean that it has to be stored in your database in this format. Convert and normalize it during upload/import and then your queries would be fast.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is an option. Short of an ETL tool (which we do not have) we'd have to still parse the information to normalize it which brings me back to my starting point... is there a better way of parsing that string that doesn't hit performance.